# Turn based Gamecenter Player Joined Notification

Tags: game-center

Is there a notification sent when a player joins a turn based gamecenter match? I can't find any documentation about it. Right now I'm polling the match data and checking when a player joins before I show my game ui...

Answer (score 0):

No, they don’t notify you when someone joins your game. The way turned based Game Center matches work is the first player creates the game and takes their turn. Then, they get notified again once someone else has join and completed their turn.